# Android PayPalPayment - Sometimes : Please make sure all fields have been entered

Tags: android, paypal, field

I try to implement in my app a payment via PayPal. The code is :

---

```
PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment();
payPalPayment.setCurrencyType("EUR");
payPalPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("10"));
amountOfMoney = 10;
if (amountToReload_RG.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == euros20_RB.getId())
{    
    payPalPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("20"));    
    amountOfMoney = 20;    
}     
else if (amountToReload_RG.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == euros30_RB.getId())    
{    
    payPalPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("30"));    
    amountOfMoney = 30;    
}    
payPalPayment.setRecipient("BLABLABLA@gmail.com");    
payPalPayment.setMerchantName("BLABLALBA");    

Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payPalPayment, this);    
this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
```

---

I have tryied this on several smartphones. It works very well on two Samsung Galaxy mini (SDK 8 and 10) but does not work properly on a htc one s (SDK 16). I always get the error message : "Please make sure all fields have been entered".

Does someone have an idea that could help me ?

Many thanks for your help!